# How to identify device out of space

Tags: disk-usage

When I try and execute commands in bash, I get an error like:

```
bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device
```

I can't even install some tools to scan the filesystem to find what's consuming all the space. When I try to install anything, it first complains that:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-headers-generic : Depends: linux-headers-3.13.0-95-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

but then when I run `sudo apt-get -f install`, that fails with:

```
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.13.0-95-generic_3.13.0-95.142_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 error creating symbolic link `./usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-95-generic/include/linux/ecryptfs.h': No space left on device
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.13.0-95-generic_3.13.0-95.142_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

However, if I run `df -H`, it shows that my / partition is only 82% full and still has 1.5G of space left.

Why is no free space being reported? How do I confirm it's referring to root, and if so, why?

Comment: Check `df -i` to see if you've run out of inodes. Also, is `/tmp` on the same partition or not?

Comment: It might be beneficial to boot a live OS to debug this. `fdisk -l` should list all the partitions on the system and how full they are.

Comment: `fdisk` doesn't have a clue about the filesystems in the partitions...

Comment: The output of `df -h /tmp` would be very useful in your Question please